# Erro ao identificar login de usuário "-Identity"

Tags: powershell

eu fiz esse script simples pra remover um determinado grupo do AD de usuários via `.csv` mas está acusando erro de que o `$_.user` não foi identificado ou está vazio.

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\antonio.costa\Documents\office365\vpn.csv"

ForEach {
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.user -MemberOf "Acesso_vpn"
}
break
```

Esse break eu adicionei pra ver ele parando na tela, mas além de dar o erro e nem para, já fecha logo.

Comment: Dá uma lida nisso: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens essa tarefa mencionada nesse **artigo**/**link:**  **https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001475**

---

> - **1)** observe o uso do  **[ForEach-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148462/difference-between-foreach-and-foreach-object-in-powershell)** , e não  o  **[ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148462/difference-between-foreach-and-foreach-object-in-powershell)**
> - **2)** observe o uso do  **[$*.'User-Name'*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148462/difference-between-foreach-and-foreach-object-in-powershell)**  , e não  o  **[$.User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148462/difference-between-foreach-and-foreach-object-in-powershell)**

---

```PowerShell
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\antonio.costa\Documents\office365\vpn.csv" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Acesso_vpn" -Member $_.'User-Name' -Confirm:$false }

# ou #

ipcsv -Path "C:\Users\antonio.costa\Documents\office365\vpn.csv" | % {Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Acesso_vpn" -Member $_.'User-Name' -Confirm:$false }
```

---

Fica a sugestão visitar essa pergunta do SOen:  **[Q29148462](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148462/difference-between-foreach-and-foreach-object-in-powershell)**

---